# I am trying to run two wordpress containers on my ubutnu machine however I keep getting many errors

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I was hoping to have two wordpress servers on two seperate IP's on my macvlan network named LAN.

Yet I somehow can only succesfully get one to work, this is quite frustrating to solve any help is appreciated.

```
version: '3'

services:
  db1:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db1_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress1
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress1
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress1
    networks:
      LAN:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.21.12  # Static IP for WordPress site 1

  wordpress1:
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:80"  # Map host port 8080 to container port 80 for WordPress site 1
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db1:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress1
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress1
    networks:
      LAN:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.21.2  # Static IP for WordPress site 1

  db2:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db2_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress2
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress2
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress2
    networks:
      LAN:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.21.13  # Static IP for WordPress site 2

  wordpress2:
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - "8081:80"  # Map host port 8081 to container port 80 for WordPress site 2
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db2:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress2
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress2
    networks:
      LAN:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.21.3  # Static IP for WordPress site 2

volumes:
  db1_data:
  db2_data:

networks:
  LAN:
    name: LAN
    external: true
```

I recive this error :

```
Creating volume "zakaria_db1_data" with default driver
Creating volume "zakaria_db2_data" with default driver
Creating zakaria_db2_1 ... 
Creating zakaria_db1_1 ... 
Creating zakaria_wordpress1_1 ... 
Creating zakaria_db2_1        ... done
Creating zakaria_db1_1        ... done
Creating zakaria_wordpress1_1 ... done
dy in use

ERROR: for wordpress2  Cannot start service wordpress2: Address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

after running my compose file.

I had ensured there is nothing running on port 80 on my machine yet stil cannot solve this issue

Is there any syntax issues or maybe conflciting port adrresses anything advice/guidance is helpful as ive been stumped.

Comment: It looks as if something is already listening on port 8081 on your host. On what OS are you running Docker (Linux/Windows/MacOS)?

Comment: @larsks its on ubuntu 22:04

Comment: What's the output of `sudo netstat -tlnp | grep 8081`? Or is there already a host on the network at address `172.16.21.3`?